# Chromatic Number Range of Dual Graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, planar-graphs, topological-graph-theory

A planar graph $G$ has some set of embeddings $\{E_\gamma:G \hookrightarrow R^2\}$.
Each of these embeddings has associated with it a geometric dual graph $G^*_\gamma$.
Using $\chi$ to denote chromatic number:

> For a given graph $G$, what is known about the set of integers
> $\{\chi(G^*_\gamma)\}$? Is it, for instance, guaranteed to be an
> interval?

A similar question can be asked about cellular embeddings of $G$ on higher-genus surfaces:

> For a given $G$, what is known about the chromatic numbers of the
> surface duals of cellular embeddings of $G$? What about those
> embeddings which have the same genus?

Comment: Some initial thoughts that you've probably already considered: the possibility space is not very large (i.e. $\{\chi(G^*_\gamma)\} \subset \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ via the 4-color theorem + the dual of a plane graph is planar). Other simplifications may arise on a case-by-case basis; for instance, it is known that if any planar embedding of $G$ is Eulerian, then $\{\chi(G^*_\gamma)\} \subset \{1, 2\}$. As another example, if we know that $G$ is a forest, then $\{\chi(G^*_\gamma)\} \subset \{1, 2, 3\}$. This isn't a general answer to your question, just some spitballing with brute force and ignorance.